# PHP - Array in implode

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to put an array into a query but I doens't work. I'm tying it with implode() but then it gives me " Array to string conversion in ... on line 26". Why? With json_encode it worked out ...

Thanks for your help!

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT follows
            FROM follow 
             WHERE follower LIKE '".$id."'") or die (mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) < 1){
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Follow someone";
} else {
    //Put all the id's of the users the user is following in an array. 
    $i = 0;
    $user_follows = array();
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) )
        {
            $user_follows[$i] = $row;
            $i++;
        }

    $user_follows = implode(" , ", $user_follows);
    echo $user_follows;
}
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated and should no longer be used. Please use mysqli instead.

Comment: What is on line 26?  I only count 20 lines of source code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `implode` must be an array of strings. But you're doing:

```
$user_follows[$i] = $row;
```

Since `$row` is an array, you're making an array of arrays (a 2-dimensional array), not an array of strings. That should be:

```
$user_follows[] = $row['follows'];
```

You don't need the `$i` variable, assigning to `$array[]` appends a new element to the array.